# Jasmine/Sinon - Triggering jQuery UI close button callback

Tags: jquery-ui, jasmine, karma-jasmine, sinon, jasmine-jquery

I have a dialog with an OK button, and once this OK button is clicked a callback method is invoked.

I am writing unit tests for this, however I cannot seem to find a way how to click on the OK button to invoke this method.  Can someone tell me how this can be done?  I am new to Jasmine & sinon.

**EDIT**: 
Here is a generic method I am using to create the dialog.

```js
function myDialogMethod(title, message, buttonLabel, buttonCallback) {
  $("#DialogMessage").html(message);

  $("#myDialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: title,
    buttons: [
      {
        text: buttonLabel,
        click: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
          buttonCallback();
        }
      }
    ]
  });
}
```

Then I call it using:

```js
myDialogMethod("Modal Title", "Modal Message", "OK", function() {
  alert("callback");
});
```

What I need to do is in the unit test click on the OK button to make sure that the button callback was invoked.

Comment: Could you please post some code related to the problem?

Comment: @MichaelRadionov added sample code

Answer (score 0):

Here is an unit test solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
import $ from "jquery";

export function myDialogMethod(title, message, buttonLabel, buttonCallback) {
  $("#DialogMessage").html(message);

  ($("#myDialog") as any).dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: title,
    buttons: [
      {
        text: buttonLabel,
        click: function() {
          ($(this) as any).dialog("close");
          buttonCallback();
        }
      }
    ]
  });
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import sinon from "sinon";
import proxyquire from "proxyquire";

describe("31940184", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it("myDialogMethod", () => {
    let buttons;
    const dialogStub = sinon.stub().callsFake(options => {
      buttons = options.buttons;
    });
    const htmlStub = sinon.stub();
    const jquerySpy = sinon.stub().callsFake(() => {
      return {
        html: htmlStub,
        dialog: dialogStub
      };
    });
    const { myDialogMethod } = proxyquire("./", {
      jquery: jquerySpy
    });
    let alert = sinon.stub();
    const buttonCallback = function() {
      alert("callback");
    };
    const buttonCallbackSpy = sinon.spy(buttonCallback);
    myDialogMethod("Modal Title", "Modal Message", "OK", buttonCallbackSpy);
    sinon.assert.calledWith(jquerySpy.firstCall, "#DialogMessage");
    sinon.assert.calledWith(jquerySpy.secondCall, "#myDialog");
    sinon.assert.calledWith(dialogStub.firstCall, {
      modal: true,
      title: "Modal Title",
      buttons: [{ text: "OK", click: sinon.match.func }]
    });
    const button = buttons[0];
    button.click();
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(buttonCallbackSpy);
    sinon.assert.calledWith(alert, "callback");
    sinon.assert.calledWith(jquerySpy.thirdCall, button);
    sinon.assert.calledWith(dialogStub.secondCall, "close");
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
31940184
    ✓ myDialogMethod (167ms)


  1 passing (174ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.spec.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/31940184